# Searching between two dates in rails activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm receiving a date in my parameters and searching the database to see if the date falls between start date and end date.  My code is the following.

```
    date = params[:date]

    record = Campaign.where(['start_date < ? AND end_date > ?', date, date])
```

This only returns each records name.  But when I try to access the full record, like its id, rails throws an error.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you run with `first` at the end? Please post your error.

Comment: Whenever you run into an error, it's good practice to include the exact text of that error. I'm with @TheShalit on this one. It looks like you've obtained an ActiveRecord Relation, rather than the single ActiveRecord object you think you should be obtaining. Add `.first` to the end of your query.

Comment: It is returning the desired output, it is just in a ActiveRecord_Relation object. You need to get your record out of the object. If you need all objects, you need to loop over the relation  and access the ids and if you need only one object, you use `.first` method or the `.last` method depending on the use case

Comment: Can you please post the error in your question that rails is giving you?

Answer (score 28):

Try This this is the rails format to check date between two date.

```
start_date = params[:start_date].to_date.beginning_of_day
end_date = params[:end_date].to_date.end_of_day
records = Campaign.where(:created_at => start_date..end_date)
```

It will return array of campaigns created in given date range.

Hope it will helps.

Answer (score 9):

You're query should look like this (note the absence of the square brackets which you include in your query.

```
date = params[:date]
record = Campaign.where('start_date < ? AND end_date > ?', date, date)
```

This will return an array of Campaigns where the date falls between it's start_date and end_date.  Therefore, you could not just say `record.id` because record is actually an array of Campaign objects.

Instead, try looping through the result to access the individual elements in the array of campaigns.

```
record.each do |record_object|  
    # perform some action on each record_object here
end
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Campaign.where(
  "created_at >= :start_date AND created_at <= :end_date",
  { start_date: params[:start_date],
    end_date: params[:end_date]}
)
```

Hope it will helps.